# Is there a booking site for chartering flights?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, charter

Are there booking sites for chartering flights? A Google journey revealed many sites where one could enquire for details on chartering a plane, but so far all the enquiring needs to be done by sending an email.

Are there sites where you can indicate the number of people in your traveling party, plus origin and destination, and then get an instant quote?

In other words, I want to go from Airport A to B, with say a party of 10. I want to find out how much would that cost me if I rent a complete plane with pilots instead of booking 10 tickets.

Comment: Are you looking for within a geographic region (eg within Europe or within the US), or world-wide?

Comment: Most charter companies are small enough that they wouldn't be able to give you an automatic quote. Their prices are also dependent on a lot of variables that would be hard to factor into an automatic quote system.

Comment: There are two uses of the word 'charter' in air travel. One is where you rent an entire plane to fly to some destination. That is what I assume you are asking about. The other is where an owner rents a plane for an entire flight (to a specific place at a specific time) to a company - typically a package vacation provider. The vacation provider then sells on individual tickets on that flight, usually as part of a vacation package. The latter are 'charter airlines' and function in many ways like scheduled airlines, and you can sometimes buy tickets on them just as you would a scheduled flight

Comment: @Andra - could you perhaps clarify which 'charter' you mean then, just to prevent the need for 'assumptions' as DJClayworth just did, and I can establish whether I need to change my answer.

Comment: I am asking for renting a plane. I want to go from Airport A to B, with say a party of 10. How much would that cost me if I rent a complete plane with pilots, in stead of booking 10 tickets

Answer (score 5):

The website [socialflights.com](https://www.socialflights.com/) offers the service you are looking for.  You can search for an available seat on an a private aircraft already chartered by someone else, or click "[Get a quote](https://www.socialflights.com/?pg=create_flight)" to get an offer (not instantly) for traveling from airport A to airport B with X people.

Unfortunately listings for available seats are currently rather limited.  You can get a list of all the available flights simply by doing a search with no criteria:

[image]

Comment: It seems only works for US domestic flights

Comment: The link in the post doesn't work, removing the https and going to the non-ssl site reveals it's apparently under construction (as of today) - I guess they're rebuilding it

Comment: This site appears to be down.

Comment: SocialFlights is now down, unfortunately.