# Are there charter flights between Australia and New Zealand that you can join?

Tags: air-travel, australia, new-zealand, charter

I don't mean chartering my own flight, but like [someone else mentioned that socialflights does in the US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/is-there-a-booking-site-for-chartering-flights), I was wondering if something similar existed for trans-Tasman flights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have yet to see anything similar to Social Flights in this part of the world, and even Social Flights appears to have closed down so I'm not sure how viable a business model it would be.

The only thing close that I've seen in Australia is [EmptyJets](http://www.emptyjets.com.au/) - a site where charter aircraft operators can list flights that would otherwise be flown empty (eg: the return leg of a one way charter). Users of the site can choose to buy a seat or the entire aircraft at a substantially reduced cost.

I have seen some of the costs involved in chartering an aircraft to fly trans-Tasman, and unless you require the flexibility of a charter then it's likely to be more cost effective to book on a commercial flight - there's plenty of them (eg: up to 15 flights a day between Sydney and Auckland).